# Redirection to custom error page not happening on server box

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <clear />
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/Apology" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot\absence" />
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/Apology" />
    </httpErrors>
```

Added above line of code in `web.config` to redirect to Error controller apology action when 404 or 403 error occurred which is working locally but not on server box.

Comment: Double check the web.config on the production environment to make sure it definitely still has it in there

Comment: i have confirmed web.config file on production. its there with above value